# How do I make IIS serve a .scs file?

Tags: iis, server

I apologize in advance if I refer to something incorrectly, this is not my area of expertise, but I do encourage being corrected so I can learn!

I am trying to allow users to access a file with the extension .scs.
Files are being served up using an IIS server.
This works for other file types like svg.
For example, the URL following url shows me a picture:
http://localhost:1234/models/UserLogo.svg
But the following URL redirects me to my home page (I set up angular to do this when it does not recognize the URL):
http://localhost:1234/models/model.scs

I have setup mime types to accept .svg as well as .*:

[image]

[image]

I don't think this did anything, but I enabled directory browsing.
I can confirm the .scs file is present in the folder I am trying to access.
Not sure if this is related but these are my response headers:
[image]

Similarly, I did set request filtering of .scs to true.
[image]

Everything else is set to the default IIS 10 settings.

Comment: Id suggest trying to figure out if your issue is angular or IIS thats generating the rewrite. Can you post the HTTP headers of the redirect? Can you setup a temp site without angular and just check IIS will serve that filetype?

Comment: It seems the problem may not be caused by mime type, please check if you specify any redirect/rewrite rule in your IIS or in `web.config` of your project ?